# Through the Processes of Jhana does it have a Permanent effect or temporary effect on your life

Tags: jhana, meditation-concentration

Is Jhana like a meditative absorption state?  I've come across this term.

Is Jhana like a barrier, once broken, you go onto the next barrier, and so on and so on. Is this process a permanent effect on the mind or a temporary effect of the mind? Do you basically start over from stage 1 every time, does your body ever become accustomed to it, and do you have to constantly renew the Jhana over and over in order to progress?

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but can process really be "permanent"? Perhaps "continuous" or did you want to ask, is jhana a permanent _state_?

Comment: I guess with the meaning of process it is a series of steps or actions to reach an end. In that format I had before It was confusing. Thank you for bringing that to my attention so I can make my question Clear for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"Jhana is like a meditative absorption state? I've come across this term."**

> "[Jhanas are] distinctive meditative states of high concentration in which the mind becomes unified. [...] Jhana is often referred to as an absorption state, since the mind in Jhana is so deeply concentrated that it 'absorbs' into the meditation object."
>
> Richard Sankman, The Experience of Samadhi

Yes. Jhana also corresponds to "right concentration" (samma samadhi) in the eightfold path (see [SN 45.8](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.008.than.html)).

**"Like a barrier once broken you go onto the next barrier an so on an so on."**

Yes. There are multiple jhanas. The canon describes a sequence of 4 Jhanas followed by 4 more states (in later commentaries, they are known respectively as *Rūpajhānas* and *Arūpajhānas*). The commentarial tradition also expanded on the states that precede the first Jhana (e.g. access concentration).

**"Is this process a permanent effect on the mind or a temporary effect of the mind, Do you basically start over from stage 1 every time [?]"**

It may affect the mind in many ways, but one doesn't really stays permanently absorbed in Jhana during day-to-day. Reaching a certain Jhana may not necessarily require going through previous jhanas (though it is emphatically advised to perfectly master them in sequence and develop stability instead of trying to "jump around").

**"does your body ever become accustomed to it [?]"**

I'm not aware of any body related issues associated with Jhana.

**"do you have to constantly renew the Jahana over an over in order to progress?"**

I'm not sure what you mean by "renew", but just like any training that requires repeated practice, mastering jhanas also requires effort and training, specially to reach deeper Jhana states.